# Why for loop is printing sop first and then running rest of code (see code inside)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Which I run in eclipse.
I am getting an unusual output (see below)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testcase ;
        String s1;
        String s2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter test cases");
        testcase = sc.nextInt();

for(int i=1 ; i<=testcase; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter String 1");
    s1= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter String 2");
    s2= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(WeightChecker.checkStringWeight(s1, s2));
}


}
```

the output is

```
Enter test cases
2
Enter String 1
Enter String 2
timepass
2
Enter String 1
time
Enter String 2
starts
2
```

I even used debug and here in first iteration `s1=""` and `s2=""`
my  question is why it is happening here?

and what could be the possible solution for same

I saw people is marking this question to another question but that question is completely different

Comment: Maybe something stays in the stamp when you enter `2` before the loop.. aaaand.. yup, `\n` it is, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: Maybe try using sc.next(); , before

Comment: Maybe try using ###sc.next(); before the ###for-loop right after the ###testcase = sc.nextInt();